# How do I get the username or PID in Access while using User level security?

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to get the username or personal ID of a user using user level security with Microsoft Access through VBA?  If so, how do I do this?  Just to clarify, I'm **not** looking to get the windows username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currentuser.  Note that if you are not using User Level Security in Access this will return the default Admin.

**Added:**
According to the [PID and its use Options](http://groups.google.ca/group/microsoft.public.access.security/browse_frm/thread/c455c11b21a5cfe2/2600074b2503cbb8) discussion you can't access the PID.     The fourth posting down by Michael Kaplan states "It [the PID] can never be retrieved at all."   And [Michael Kaplan](http://trigeminal.com/) was on the Microsoft Access Product Group and thoroughly understands Access.

Comment: That's okay... I'd prefer the username anyway.  Thanks!